# Android - Pick multiple contacts

Tags: java, android

I'm aware that there is some old answer on here regarding on how to do this but was hoping for a more updated version.

I want to let the user pick multiple contacts from their phone and add it to an array.
I'm using ContactContract with PICK_CONTENT.

So far I have got the following:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode,resultCode,data);

        switch (reqCode){
            case(PICK_CONTACT):
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor phone = getContentResolver().query(contactData,null,null,null,null);
                    PlayerDetails player = new PlayerDetails(); //TODO turn this into a loop to add each player the user picks and then display it
                    if(phone.moveToFirst()) {

                        player.name = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        player.number =phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        playerListGame.addPlayer(player);
```

But this clicking a button to launch this activity and then :

```
 public void showPlayerGameList(){
        playerTextView = findViewById(R.id.aPlayerBox);
        for(PlayerDetails i : playerListGame.myPlayers){
            playerTextView.append(i.name + "\n" + i.number); //TODO sort this out so it doesnt repeat the same names
        }
    }
```

Then I loop through the array I add it to, to display the info I need.

I don't know how to get the application to allow the user to select multiple users

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually SO doesn't take too kindly to questions that ask "How do I do X?" without demonstrating that some effort has been made by the asker to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @pushasha I've added more info to my desc to help resolve this issue. Hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know it is late but i hope someone else or even you can implement in this way.

---

Launching CONTACTS intent with PICK_CONTACT will not be able to pick multiple contacts. Even if you manage to select multiple contacts on some device, It would not work on most of the other devices and versions of android systems. As i have tried in the same way before..

---

Then created a `listview` with `multiple choce` and given a list of contacts to `adapter` of the listview. Now how to get contacts list..

---

```
ContactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContactsNumbersList = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();

    // Contacts Database queries

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, null, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY +" ASC");


    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-","");
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ","");
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(","");
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")","");

        if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(phoneNumber))
        {
            ContactsList.add(name);
            ContactsNumbersList.add(phoneNumber);
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
```